# Clickable map in webgl

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, geocoding

I am able to render a 3d earth using three.js by adding a world map image texture onto a sphere. I intend to make this globe clickable. ie., whenever user clicks on any country, the country's border should be highlighted. Is it possible to attain this functionality by using the world map jpeg containing the national borders? Is it somehow possible to check if the user clicked inside some boundaries of a country? Another option could be to load geojson of World countries and transform svg into canvas. However, I am still not sure how to make countries clickable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use color IDs per country and then check the color of the pixel you clicked on. [This tutorial](http://mflux.tumblr.com/post/28367579774/armstradeviz) explains how to do this.

Comment: when trying the code from teh tutorial, I get an error referring to  THREE.Curve.Utils.createLineGeometry( points ) function. 
Is this function deprecated ? What alternative am I supposed to use in its place?